# Grub Rescue (UEFI Laptop)

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, grubrescue

I installed Ubuntu couple days ago and suddenly the sound stopped working, could not find the solution and since i had not setup or put too much effort into it, I decided to just go ahead and resinstall.

I have an Asus laptop with Windows 8 UEFI and I was dual booting just fine.

After reinstalling Ubuntu it had a host of problems, no sound, wirelss was not working, trackpad was not working etc etc. I decided to do one more reinstall to see if I had more luck.

Now it just boots into Grub Rescue and thanks to this "genius" forced EUFI feature i can't access the bios and change the stupid boat order.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get into firmware by hitting F2/F12/Del *quickly* after rebooting/powering on the notebook.

Just in case, I'm doing weekly releases of [ALT Linux Rescue](http://en.altlinux.org/Rescue) which supports UEFI and can live with SecureBoot enabled -- there's efibootmgr there so you can tweak the boot order either (although firmware might be easier).